# Get EMDK version programmatically on Android

Tags: android, motorola-emdk

How to get EMDK version of an Android device programmatically?

Since this question is not asked on Stackoverflow, I decided to ask and answer own question to make it easily findable later when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get EMDK version programmatically.

Using Android package manager:

```
public String getEMDKVersion() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    String emdkPackage = "com.symbol.emdk.emdkservice";
    PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(emdkPackage, 0);
    String emdkVersion = pInfo.versionName;
    return emdkVersion
}
```

Using EMDK version manager:

```
public String getEMDKVersion(EMDKManager emdkManager)
{
    VersionManager versionManager = (VersionManager) emdkManager.getInstance(FEATURE_TYPE.VERSION);
    String emdkVersion = versionManager.getVersion(VersionManager.VERSION_TYPE.EMDK);
    return emdkVersion;
}
```

Comment: Seems both are same.

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical, thanks for noticing it, I somehow lost some code while formatting the answer. Now, both methods are in place.